# regex match&replace for raw string

Tags: python, regex

I don't get why following behavior of the re.sub. Anybody can explain how the strings are processed in re.sub? why statement 2 doesn't match&replace?  thanks

```
1. >>> re.sub(r'\$abc', 'ABC', r'\$abcdefg')
'\\ABCdefg'

2. >>> re.sub(r'\\$abc', 'ABC', r'\\$abcdefg')
'\\\\$abcdefg'

3. >>> r'\\$abc' in r'\\$abcdefg'
True

4. >>> re.sub(r'\\\$abc', 'ABC', r'\\\$abcdefg')
'\\\\ABCdefg'
```

Comment: well, your 2nd statement is rendering `\\\\ABCdefg`. What's your expected output

Comment: [Cannot repro either](http://ideone.com/Fv92cA)

Comment: looks like stackoverlow is messing up backslackes in my post. Now I revised it. For statement 2, I am not sure why the replacement doesn't occur. what is the difference in regex processing between statement 1/2/4?

Answer (score 0):

It is because in the pattern (*first arg*) the double back slashes `\\` turns into only one, and thus won't match.

It occurs because when the regex engine see one slash `\` it automatically escape the next character resulting `\\` in just one literal `\`.

To do the regex match the two slashes you should add two more slashes:

```
2. >>> re.sub(r'\\\\\$abc', 'ABC', r'\\\$abcdefg')
'\ABCdefg'
```

Reference: [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the help. please take a look at my revised post and comment. Even regex consumes a backslash, it should match the 3rd argument, right?

Comment: @abemaw. It seems you removed the escape character to the reserved `$` (which means the match should occur at the end of string). Was it intended? Anyways, I think the problem is because you should escape either all slashes and the `$` too.

Comment: there is no particular intention. I just don't understand how '\ ' is handled by Python's interpreter and regex engine so that the statement 2 doesn't match and replace.

Comment: @abemaw. From simple to hard: 1. `'$abc'` will match nothing due `$` is a regex reserved key which means `end of string`. Then to match the literal `$abc` you should escape this way `'\$abc'`. Right till now? ... Well, it occurs that if you want to match the literal `\ ` in the string you will have to escape it too (because it is also reserved by the regex engine). Then `'\\\$abc'` matches the literal `\$abc` and so on...

Comment: I think here I had 2 things got confused before the discussion: 1. R/r prefix will preserve the backslashes by the python interpretor but these backslashes will be interpreted as escape character in the regex engine. 2. '$' is also interpreted by the regex engine as the end of string. This explains why statement 2 doesn't match. Thanks a lot, @washington-guedes

Comment: @abemaw. I think you can understand it seeing it in action: _https://regex101.com/r/kY0aP1/1_